# MySQL stored procedure dynamic sql result

Tags: mysql

I understand it's possible to have dynamic SQL in user defined stored procedure on MySQL (>=5.0.13). So if we have something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN

    SET @query = "SELECT * FROM temp";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;       

END
```

My question is: how can I use the result of the dynamic statement that is executed?

Answer (score 0):

If the result is a single value you can load it into a variable. 
If your query retrieves a result set of multiple records you can load these into a cursor and loop through them record by record for further processing. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: or put the result in (temporary) tables.